# How to calculate RGB?

Tags: byte, rgb

I'm doing an exercise, but I'm confused on how to solve this.

> it says a public library has recently decided to digitise its archive of local newspapers from the last 50 years. The pages of the newspapers will be scanned and stored as digital colour images. Suppose that each newspaper will be scanned as a 3000 pixel wide and 6000 pixel high RGB image. The library currently own 15TB of storage( you may assume that one terabyte is equal to 1,000,000,000,0000 bytes). How manny pages of newspaper can be hosted using the library's existing storage? *note: assuage uncompressed RGB format is used, with one byte for each of the R,G, and B components*

Comment: Just read the description and add/multiply the values appropriately.  It could be kumquats instead of pixels and the technique would be the same.

Comment: (Hint, each kumquat contains 3 seeds.  The kumquats are arranged in an array 3000 wide and 6000 high.  How many kumquat seeds do you have in that array?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How many bytes are needed for a single pixel in RGB? `bits = 3`

How many pixels are in the image? `area`

How much memory is needed for a single page? `page_memory`

How many pages can be stored? `number_of_pages = total_memory / page_memory`

Final answer is 2,777,777 but since this is homework I won't post all the details.

Comment: It's not a direct answer, he has the clues.

Comment: Mihai Maruseac thanks for the explanation :) I'm a beginner and have to do a lot of exercise to become as good as you guys

Comment: " note: assuage uncompressed RGB format is used, with one byte for each of the R,G, and B components"

so 24 bits not 3 per pixel.

Answer (score 1):

1 pixel has 3 channels: Red, Green, Blue. One byte per channel means that each pixel has 3 bytes of data. There's nothing technical here.

Answer (score -1):

Each image = `3000x6000 pixels` = `18000000 pixels` = `18000000x3` bytes = `54000000 bytes`
Total storage = `150000000000000 bytes`

Therefore it can store roughly 2777777 pages of news paper.